# In Stroustrup's example, what does the colon mean in "return 1 : 2"?

Tags: c++, syntax

I don't understand one particular use of a colon.

I found it in the book [*The C++ Programming Language*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C%2B%2B_Programming_Language) by Bjarne Stroustrup, 4th edition, section 11.4.4 "Call and Return", page 297:

```
void g(double y)
{
  [&]{ f(y); }                                               // return type is void
  auto z1 = [=](int x){ return x+y; }                        // return type is double
  auto z2 = [=,y]{ if (y) return 1; else return 2; }         // error: body too complicated
                                                             // for return type deduction
  auto z3 =[y]() { return 1 : 2; }                           // return type is int
  auto z4 = [=,y]()−>int { if (y) return 1; else return 2; } // OK: explicit return type
}
```

The confusing colon appears on line 7, in the statement `return 1 : 2`. I have no idea what it could be. It's not a label or ternary operator.

It seems like a conditional ternary operator without the first member (and without the `?`), but in that case I don't understand how it could work without a condition.

Comment: It's a compile error on my end (gcc and clang). Plus all those lines need semicolons, but still an error.

Comment: **Moderator Note:** Please think very carefully before casting a vote to close this as a "typo" question. Yes, the problem is a typo, but it's not a typo that the asker made. Rather, it is one found in a published book. That means this question and its answers may well be useful to others in the future, which is a strong counter-indicator for closing it as a typo. (UPDATE: This topic is now [being discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384463); please feel free to weigh in there.)

Comment: Perhaps the best answer would be:  Try to compile the code; if it doesn't compile, that's a good indication that it's a typo.

Comment: I can think of a number of examples off the top of my head that fail to compile (or even cause an internal compiler error) on one compiler, but are accepted without issue on a different one

Comment: @John I just tried some fold expressions with MSVC and they didn't compile. So clearly the whole chapter I just read must be a typo? ;) C++ compilers fail to compile valid C++ code all the time, comes from the language being absurdly complicated.

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez All too true unfortunately that one compiler or another will fail to compile "valid" code, and perhaps C++ is especially poor in this regard.  But still the first thing to try is a compiler.

Comment: @Voo I added my "compile" comment, because the answers below failed to mention it and there's no indication from OP of any compilation errors.

Comment: use `auto z3 =[y]() { return y ? 1 : 2; }`

Comment: Probably due to the publisher not running their linter...

Answer (score 207, accepted):

It's a typo in the book. Look at [Errata for 2nd and 3rd printings of The C++ Programming Language](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th_printing3.html). The example must be like below:

```
auto z3 =[y]() { return (y) ? 1 : 2; }
```

Comment: Why `(y)` and not just `y`?

Comment: @LittleHelper Perhaps its a best practice or something, I always see it written like that. Maybe to avoid confusion with more complicated comparisons...

Comment: Personally, I often use `(cond) ? a : b` for clarity -- it helps me avoid misreading e.g. the statement `foo = x > y ? a : b` as `foo = x ...` when skimming through code.

Comment: @LittleHelper It's not really needed there.  However in a function-like macro it's best practise to put parentheses round the arguments where they are used, because otherwise expansion of the arguments can give unexpected behaviour.  Consider a function-like macro to double a value "foo(x) x * 2" where you call it with "foo(2+3)".  The result will be 2+(3*2) because the argument gets expanded as-is and precedence rules take over.  If your macro is "foo(x) (x)*2" then you will correctly get (2+3)*2.  It may be that Stroustrup has a habit of using that style everywhere for coding safety.

Comment: @Graham Very unlikely.  Stroustrup essentially doesn't write function macros (C++ inline functions are better).  Much more likely is that the ternary operator has somewhat complicated precedence rules, so it is good to habitually clarify the precedence with parens.

Comment: I have the 4th printing, April 2015, and it's correct in my copy: `auto z3 =[y]() { return (y) ? 1 : 2; };`. As for the parentheses around `y`, they're unnecessary and IMHO not particularly good style (but harmless, of course). Several other lines in that function have `(y)` for other reasons; perhaps Stroustrup just copied that.

Comment: @KeithThompson I agree. Perhaps the previous example was converted by removing keywords like  `if (y) return 1; else return 2;` -> `(y) ? 1 : 2;`

Comment: Some people just like to surround any condition in parens.

Answer (score 20):

Looks to me like a simple typo. Should probably be:

```
auto z3 =[y]() { return y ? 1 : 2; }
```

Note that since the lambda doesn't take any parameters, the parens are optional. You could use this instead, if you preferred:

```
auto z3 =[y] { return y ? 1 : 2; }
```

Answer (score 11):

`return 1 : 2;` is a syntax error, it is not valid code.

A correct statement would be more like `return (y) ? 1 : 2;` instead.